# Creating a loop for linear regression in R and print the coefficient in extra column (price elasticity)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, linear-regression, coefficients

We have only little experience with R till now and need to create a loop. We have a dataset that contains more than 150 brands with their sales volume and corresponding prices.  We need to run a regression for each brand (in order to calculate the 150 different price elasticities). Because we do not want to type every lm-function for every brand into our R script, we want to use a loop that creates the regression functions more or less automatically for each brand. Furthermore, we need to put the price-coefficient (which is the price elasticity) in another column of the dataframe (to plot the price elasticity). 
We thought of using the for() loop function, but this did not work.  We probably made a mistake in the specification of this function, because it only calculated one price elasticity across all brands. 
Do you have a idea? We are looking forward to get any help :)

This is the code for our linear regression:

Here, we created a dataframe for the brand “Budweiser”:

```
bud_all <- subset(brandlevel, brand=="Budweiser")
```

Here, we run the regression with log_move being the amount of  “Budweiser” that was sold and log_price being the price of the sold item:

```
reg_bud <-lm(log_move ~ log_price + as.factor(store), data = bud_all)
```

This is were we get our coefficient from:

```
summary(reg_bud)
```

Here is our first try of using a for loop, unfortunately there was only one price elasticity for all brands which has been calculated:

```
out <- data.frame(NULL)
for (i in 1:brandlevel$brand){
  m <- summary(lm(log_move ~ log_price, data=brandlevel))
  out[i,1] <- m$coefficients[2,1]
}
```

Comment: You are fitting the same model over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit the several models and get their coefficients using code along the lines of what follows.
Instead of the buit-in dataset `iris` and its columns `Species`, `Sepal.length` and `Petal.length`, use `brandlevel` and its columns `brand`, `log_move` and `log_price`.

```
data(iris)

out <- lapply(unique(iris$Species), function(s){
            sub_iris <- subset(iris, Species == s)
            m <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = sub_iris)
            coef(m)
        })

out <- do.call(rbind, out)
out
#     (Intercept) Sepal.Length
#[1,]   0.8030518    0.1316317
#[2,]   0.1851155    0.6864698
#[3,]   0.6104680    0.7500808
```

**EDIT.**

With your dataset and regression model (`lm` instrucion) you would do something like the following. (Untested.)

```
out <- lapply(unique(brandlevel$brand), function(b){
            sub_df <- subset(brandlevel, brand == b)
            m <- lm(log_move ~ log_price, data = sub_df)
            coef(m)
        })

out <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

Two notes.

- This is exactly the same logic as the `iris` example above.
- You don't need to call the complicated `summary` function. There are functions to extract the coefficients and other members of the return value of `lm`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried your code but R computes since more than 1 hour. I'm not sure what is meant with function(s) and species = s. Do you mean (for our data) to put in a brandname for s? The following code is what I tried:                                                     
   `out <- 
   lapply(unique(brandlevel$log_move), function(s){
     sub_brandlevel <- subset(brandlevel, brand = s)
     m <- lm(log_move ~ log_price, data = sub_brandlevel)
     coef(m)
   })

   out <- do.call(rbind, out)
   out`

Comment: Sorry, the code I tried was `out <- lapply(unique(brandlevel$brand), function(s) {`etc.

Comment: @Anna The code in your previous comment seems to be wrong because you do `unique(brandlevel$log_move)` when it should be `unique(brandlevel$brand)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code works and we got an output! One problem still remains: there is the same coefficient for every brand (like in your example) - do you have any idea what the problem is or how to solve it?

Comment: My output looks like this:       (Intercept) log_price
  `[1,]    0.658253 -2.028101
  [2,]    0.658253 -2.028101
  [3,]    0.658253 -2.028101
  [4,]    0.658253 -2.028101
  [5,]    0.658253 -2.028101` etc.

Comment: @Anna Sorry, I had a **big bug** in my code. Instead of `==` I had written just one `=` in the following instruction: `sub_df <- subset(brandlevel, brand == b)`. It is now corrected, both with `iris` and with `brandlevel`.

Comment: thank you so much!!! The code is working and calculates one price elasticity for each brand.

Comment: We've got another problem, maybe anyone can help? We have a dataframe and want to apply different types of  regressions on this dataframe (e.g. one regression without fixed effects, another with fixed effects, another one with moderator variable, etc.). In the end, we want to get the price elasticity (ß-coefficient) for each of the models (if we have 4 different regression models, we need 4 price elasticities).